# How to call function from div on load in angularjs

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, angularjs, asp.net-mvc-4

I am trying to pull value in div element and once I get value I would like to call a function to get data. I am unable to call function inside div element 
HERe is my Html

stats.html

```
<div class="ItemsList" data-ng-init="GetStatsData({{menu.result}})">
 {{myitems}}
<div>
```

RootController.js

```
function GetStatsData(resultval) {
 homeService.getitemsData(resultval)
        .success(function (data, status, headers, config) {
                        $scope.myitems = data
                });
}
```

I am getting data when calling function directly but when I try to use div tag and invoke the function I cannot get this working, Its never calling that function. My main goal is to get value in myitems passing menu.result in function.

I appreciate any help to get this resolved

Comment: You need to share more code... what is menu.result? where is it defined? Where are you initializing it, etc... Also, it would help if you shared a jsfiddle or a plunker with the isolated issue. Thanks! And BTW when you call the function, you don't need to interpolate the 'menu.result'

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As mentioned in the documentation  [ngInit](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngInit)
`The only appropriate use of ngInit is for aliasing special properties of ngRepeat`

You should change the way you you call `GetStatsData` to be called from the controller as follow

```
$scope.group.menuData = []   // set the array of data here

for(n = 0, n <  $scope.group.menuData.length, n++) {
   // wrap you async calls inside function when in loop
   $(function(index) {
       //CALL GetStatsData
       GetStatsData($scope.group.menuData[index]);
   })(n);
}
```

The implementation of GetStatsData need little modification

```
function GetStatsData(menu) {
     homeService.getitemsData(menu.result)
    .success(function (data, status, headers, config) {
                    menu.myitems = data
            });
}
```

Now your view html should be like this

```
<div class="ItemsList">
  {{menu.myitems}}
 <div>
```